# Log in WSO2 Identity Server (IS) with Kerberos authentication

Tags: authentication, kerberos, wso2-identity-server

I would like to authenticate automatically to wso2 IS with a kerberos ticket obtained from kerberos authentication (using Windows server 2K12 as KDC).

I didn't find any information related to kerberos authentication on WSO2 documentation. The list of all handled are defined here : https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS460/Managing+the+Identity+Server.

The one that is closer to kerberos authentication is the "integrated windows authentication".

Have I missed the documentation page or is it impossible to authenticate with this methods ?

I think I should go with https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Creating+Custom+Authenticators but not sure about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you basally need the window authentication?  It means once you login to windows machine, you can access the service protected with Identity Server by default. In IS 5.0.0 version, you can find IWA authentication that can be used for external application authentication and login to WSO2IS management console. There is some aricle that explain about this.  Please refer it from [here](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/04/integrated-windows-authentication-wso2-identity-server/) you can use it.

Yes. you can plug custom authenticator.. But i guess IWA can help you to achieve this.

Comment: Hi. First of all, thanks for your reply. I've followed your link and as expected IWA is using NTLM which is restricted to windows environment only. I would like to have kerberos authentication instead, that is, in my opinion, different from WSO2's IWA.